# Refresh/Reload a page(1st page) from another page (3rd page) in React js

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I want to reload  page 1st from another page  using react js,
I try method windoe.location.reload(),location.reload() but not working.

Comment: You will have to provide **a lot** more information than this

Comment: let i have two user seeker and mentor , both login own device and  on the mentor's home page have button for refresh if mentor click on refresh button  then another user seeker's home page should be refresh.

Comment: You'd have the "seeker" do a constant poll on the server and wait until the server responds with something like "refresh now". You will of course have to implement all of these and it's not an easy task. I suggest you break it down into manageable bits and then you can ask questions on any implementation difficulties you have on specific issues. I think this is just too broad.